# Submit Form with jQuery don't work on Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

I use this code to submit a file to my webserver with `jQuery`:

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="20" onChange="$('#ajaxupload').fadeIn();$(this).closest('form').submit(); return false;" style="display : none;" />
<input type="submit" value="Neue Datei hinzuf&uuml;gen" onclick="$('#userfile').click(); return false;" />
```

This works fine on `Firefox`, `Safari` but it don't work on `Internet Explorer`, so what's wrong here?

Comment: What's "doesn't work"? It doesn't submit?

Comment: Sorry, yes it doesn't submit. jQuery starts the Ajax Gif ($('#ajaxupload').fadeIn();), but that's all!

Comment: you should not mix up html and jquery this way. try to use it in external js file.

Answer (score 0):

`onChange` is not supported in that version of IE that you're using obviously. Try [jQuery's `.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) instead

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.userfile').change(function () {
        $('#ajaxupload').fadeIn();
        $(this).closest('form').submit(); 
        return false;
    });

    $('.submitUserFile').click(function () {
        $('#userfile').click();
        return false;
    });
</script>

<input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="20" style="display : none;" />
<input type="submit" id="submitUserFile" value="Neue Datei hinzuf&uuml;gen" />
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it but the result is the same! I think there is something wrong withe the submit?, because $('#ajaxupload').fadeIn(); is triggerd everytime!

Comment: made a new answer. i removed all the jQuery script inside the `<input>`'s and hopefuly it will work. maybe it's `ajaxupload` fadeIn function that's messing up ... do you include any jQuery library? `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" />`

Comment: Of course I included jQuery.I tried your solution, but it don't work. If I make the userfile visible and only use this (excluding the submit) with your solution everything is fine :-(, but that's really ugly.